# Why mortality rate is taken as locally integrable function?

Tags: mathematical-modeling, geometric-measure-theory, biology

In most of the population dynamics models, mortality rate is taken as locally integrable function not integrable  but the birth rate is taken as essentially bounded measurable function. What is the reason behind this.

Comment: I'd say, because it would be a strange model if suddenly infinitely many animals die/are born.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven can you please elaborate this little with more.

Comment: Ok, assume you want to model some population, say humans. Usually you would like to consider only finitely many people and only finitely many die or are born. So in particular both the birth rate and the mortality rate would be bounded and hence locally integrable. But I am by no means an expert in the this kind of field.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven every bounded function is not [locally integrable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_integrable_function). I think you have not understood my question.

Comment: Every bounded function is locally integrable (unless you use some measure space where compact sets might have infinite measure). That is because $$\int_K \vert f(x) \vert d\mu(x) \leq \sup_{x\in K} \vert f(x)\vert \cdot \mu(K)$$

Comment: I think you are confusing integrable and locally integrable.

Comment: Exactly I want to know why birth rate is taken as locally integrable (most times) and not integrable but that is not true in case of mortality rate.

Comment: Because we also want to model constant birth and death rate and obviously they are not integrable. You might want to formulate your question in a better way, that is not at all clear from what you wrote.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven strictly speaking not every bounded function is locally integrable because not every bounded function is measurable. But non-measurable functions should not be considered acceptable candidates for any function describing some real word phenomenon.

Comment: @s.harp I fail to see what kind of value the comment of yours was supposed to generate.

Comment: @Severin I was remarking on your comments that every bounded function is locally integrable. It seemed to me that this was a problem of the OP with your remark. There is no need to be defensive..

Comment: @s.harp The OP did not reply to that remark... I think that measurability cannot really be an issue as he talking about essentially bounded and (local) integrability that was why I conceived your comment as unnecessary nitpicking. Sorry for that

Comment: @s.harp your first comment clarify my doubts. Thanks for the help.